# SOLVED AWS CloudFormation Create stack. Unresolved resource dependencies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a VPC that has a couple of subnets, security group, and internet gateways. I get the error "Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [VPCSubnet03]"

here's part of my .yml file

```
Parameters:
  Subnet03CIDRBlock:
     Type: String
     Description: CIDR Block range for the public subnet 03 in the VPC if the region has more than 2 Availability Zones.


Conditions:
  Has2Azs:
    Fn::Or:
      - Fn::Equals:
        - {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
        - us-west-2
      - Fn::Equals:
        - {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
        - us-east-1
      - Fn::Equals:
        - {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
        - me-south-1
  
  HasMore:
    Fn::Not:
      - Condition: Has2Azs

Resources:
   VPCSubnet03:
      Condition: HasMore
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
          VpcId: !Ref VPC
          CidrBlock: !Ref Subnet03CIDRBlock
          AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 2, !GetAZs '' ]
          Tags:
              - Key: Name
                Value: !Sub "${ProjectName}-Subnet03CIDRBlock"
```

and for reference, here's also my .json parameter file

```
[{
   "ParameterKey": "Subnet03CIDRBlock",
   "ParameterValue": "192.168.3.0/24"
},
{
   "ParameterKey": "ProjectName",
   "ParameterValue": "GreenBlueDeployment"
}]
```

I have googled for a bit and I have no idea what I am supposed to fix. AFAIK, all the dependencies in the VPCSubnet03 are defined.

**EDIT:**
I had established a condition in my definition of the VPCSubnet03 and forgot to add the same condition in the respective association route table resource. Now the stack is being created!

Here's how the final sample looks like after updating my .yml file:

```
Parameters:
  Subnet03CIDRBlock:
     Type: String
     Description: CIDR Block range for the public subnet 03 in the VPC if the region has more than 2 Availability Zones.


Conditions:
  Has2Azs:
    Fn::Or:
      - Fn::Equals:
        - {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
        - us-west-2
      - Fn::Equals:
        - {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
        - us-east-1
      - Fn::Equals:
        - {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
        - me-south-1

  HasMore:
    Fn::Not:
      - Condition: Has2Azs

Resources:
   VPCSubnet03:
      Condition: HasMore
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
          VpcId: !Ref VPC
          CidrBlock: !Ref Subnet03CIDRBlock
          AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 2, !GetAZs '' ]
          Tags:
              - Key: Name
                Value: !Sub "${ProjectName}-Subnet03CIDRBlock"

   Subnet03RouteTableAssociation:
      Condition: HasMore
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
          SubnetId: !Ref VPCSubnet03
          RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
```

Thank you again for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see more detailed errors inline:

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

Would need to run [`cfn-lint`](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) on the full template to know for sure though

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't know this tool existed. I tried it out and ran it across my file through the terminal, and got the following error, which makes sense according to the logic i'm constructing:`Ref to resource "VPCSubnet03" that may not be available when condition "HasMore" is False at Resources/Subnet03RouteTableAssociation/Properties/SubnetId/Ref
KubernetesVPC.yml:137:11 `

Comment: I had forgotten to add a Condition attribute at my Subnet03RouteTableAssoc to match with my VPCSubnet03 condition. All is working as intended. I'll update my post. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your template is missing `ProjectName` and `VPC` parameters. Thus it should be:

```
Parameters:

  Subnet03CIDRBlock:
     Type: String
     Description: CIDR Block range for the public subnet 03 in the VPC if the region has more than 2 Availability Zones.

  ProjectName:
     Type: String
     Default: my-project-name

  VPC:
     Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id  


Conditions:
  Has2Azs:
    Fn::Or:
      - Fn::Equals:
        - {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
        - us-west-2
      - Fn::Equals:
        - {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
        - us-east-1
      - Fn::Equals:
        - {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
        - me-south-1
  
  HasMore:
    Fn::Not:
      - Condition: Has2Azs

Resources:


   VPCSubnet03:
      Condition: HasMore
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
          VpcId: !Ref VPC
          CidrBlock: !Ref Subnet03CIDRBlock
          AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 2, !GetAZs '' ]
          Tags:
              - Key: Name
                Value: !Sub "${ProjectName}-Subnet03CIDRBlock"
```

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct there, I have already defined my VPC as a resource and defined its CidrBlock in my parameter file as well as my ProjectName property. But I'm still getting the error

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAyman You need to provide more details. Which region are you deploying into? What subnets do you use? How do you invoke your CLI to create the stack.

Comment: Yup, I realised I had added the condition and forgot to add the same condition to my route association table, and after I did that it worked. I use a create.sh script that has the following code: `aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name $1 --template-body file://$2  --parameters file://$3 --capabilities "CAPABILITY_IAM" "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM" --region=us-west-2`